# Script for changing CSV into Key Value (KV) format

Tags: shell-script, shell, csv

I have a CSV file with data as below:

```
row_identifier,DBNAME,tblsps_name,Cur_size,Max_size,Used,Free,Percentage
tablespace,MRETF,RERETOSB15_DATA,51200,45600,14284,31316,31
tablespace,MRETF,SPOTLIGHT_DATA,500,2000,259,1741,13
tablespace,MRETF,DDLAUDITING,25,25,2,23,8
```

I need the output in the following format:

```
tablespace,MRETF,tblsps_name:RERETOSB15_DATA,Cur_size:51200,Max_size:45600,Used:14284,Free:31316,Percentage:31
tablespace,MRETF,tblsps_name:SPOTLIGHT_DATA,Cur_size:500,Max_size:2000,Used:259,Free:1741,
```

and so on..
Basically I need the output as key(column name):value

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51823532/7552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)Arr[i]=$i;next}{printf("%s,",$1);for(j=2;j<=NF;j++){printf("%s:%s,",Arr[j],$j)}printf("\n")}' filename.csv
tablespace,DBNAME:MRETF,tblsps_name:RERETOSB15_DATA,Cur_size:51200,Max_size:45600,Used:14284,Free:31316,Percentage:31, 
tablespace,DBNAME:MRETF,tblsps_name:SPOTLIGHT_DATA,Cur_size:500,Max_size:2000,Used:259,Free:1741,Percentage:13,
tablespace,DBNAME:MRETF,tblsps_name:DDLAUDITING,Cur_size:25,Max_size:25,Used:2,Free:23,Percentage:8,
```

why DBNAME was not there in your output ?

Comment: thanks.. DBNAME will be common throughout. So key value is not required on DBNAME